# Scanner error at end of line

Tags: java

I am reading in from a csv file. Each line is an object with the fields for that object on one line. The last value on every line happens to be a double. If I read it with scan.nextDouble() I get an inputMismatchException. I'm assuming it's because of the newline character. If i read it in as a string it works no problem, then I could try to parse it to a double but I would like to know why the end of the line causes errors in the first place.

The file itself is 120000 lines long, if I skip over the last value for each and just call nextLine() everything works. When I try to read in that last double I get errors. Any help would be appreaciated. I posted this question very late last night but was met with people too preoccupied with formatting my sample and making my code meet some google code requirement. I played around with it, and narrowed it down to trying to read the last value as a double that doesn't work.

I'm using this as a scanner:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv")));
scan.useDelimiter(",");
```

It ignores the commas just fine, I have tried making the newline character a delimiter as well but it crashes horribly.

3 lines from the file:

```
0,0,Sol,-26.7,4.85,G2V,0.656,0.000005,0,0,0,0,0
0.00006,1.089009,,9.1,2.39,F5,0.482,219.740502,0.003449,4.177065,0.00000004,-0.00000554,-0.000002
0.000283,-19.49884,,9.27,5.866,K3V,0.999,45.210918,0.003365,-16.008996,-0.00000007,0.00004213,-0.0000002
```

The first line has the correct number of fields. 
I thought that maybe the values are too big bit-wise to fit, but I tried to convert the string to a double and have just realized that it's trying to put "0 \n 0.00006 into a double. Again, I think it's the newline not being recognized as a delimiter by the scanner.

Comment: Could you provide a short sample of how your lines look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, using just a comma for a delimiter would not work. `Scanner` works by reading in all incoming data until the next occurrence of the delimiter. Suppose this is your file:

```
ABC,123,24.5
DEF,456,29
```

Now, when it comes to the third token, it will take `24.5\nDEF` to be your next token. Then it will try to parse that as a double. Of course, this won't work.

So, you can do one of two things:

1. Read line by line using `nextLine()`, split the line on the commas, and then parse each of the tokens.
2. Allow the delimiter to be either comma or an end-of-line:

   ```
   scan.useDelimiter(",|\r?\n");
   ```

   This tells the scanner that if it sees either a comma or a line separator (the optional `\r` is for windows-style line separator), then it's the end of the token.

Comment: This worked, now I am getting an inputmismatchexception after reading in 46 lines. Always 46 lines even if I start somewhere else in the file.

Comment: 0.00885,-3.306323,,7.91,0.281,K2,1.104,335.01103,0.776192,-19.353759,0.00000146,0.00001806,0.00002605                                                        If I throw in 25 nextLine()s it starts reading properly, but then 25+46 lines later I get the same exception.

Comment: You have two consecutive commas there. If your file is truely CSV, this means that there is an empty token between them, and therefore it cannot be read by `nextDouble`. So you might want to test that case first. For example, check whether `hasNextDouble()` is false even though `hasNext()` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```java
scan.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line separator"));
```

Comment: And what if the file is from a different machine with a different line separator setting?